# Recursive Descent Parser for C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm looking for a parser for C.  Here is what I need:

1. Written in C (*not* C++).
2. Handwritten (not generated).
3. BSD or similarly permissive license.
4. Capable of nontrivially parsing itself (can be a subset of C).

It can be part of a project as long as it's decoupled so that I can pull out the parser.

Is there an existing parser that fulfills these requirements?

Comment: Why do you care how the parser is constructed?  More importantly, if you are working with an arbitrary subset of C, why would you want a parser that harder to modify ("handwritten") than one generated from a specification document in which the grammer was precisely delineated?

Comment: And just to be pedantic, how *small* a subset of C?  Technically, the empty language can parse itself :-}

Comment: @Ira I care because I'm using it as a bootstrapping starting point for a C-like domain-specific language.  It won't always be C, so if I generate it I will eventually have to deal with generated code by hand.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need C99, then [lcc](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/software/lcc/) is a slam dunk:

- It is documented in a very clear, well-written book.
- Techniques used for recursive-descent parsing of operators with precedence are well documented in an article and technical report by Dave Hanson.
- Clear, handwritten ANSI C code.

One potential downside is that the `lcc` parser does not build an abstract-syntax tree—it goes straight from parsing to intermediate code.

If you must have C99 then I think tinycc (tcc) is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

How about [Sparse](http://sparse.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)?

Answer (score 1):

You could try [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/).  It's licensed under the Lesser GPL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net) sufficiently agrees with your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Good c compiler is present at this location. Simple and accessible.
https://github.com/rui314/8cc

Answer (score -1):

GCC has one in gcc/c-parser.c.

Comment: That doesn't really fill the licensing requirements. Just saying.

Answer (score -1):

Check elsa, it uses the Generalized LR algorithm.

Its main use is for C++, but it also parses C code.

Check on its [page](http://scottmcpeak.com/elkhound/), on the section called "How much C can Elsa parse?" which says it can parse most C programs, including the Linux kernel.

It's released under a BSD license.

Comment: Elsa is not entirely hand-written; it uses Elkhound as a parser generator. The main grammar file is a .gr file that is passed through Elkhound to generate a parser

Answer (score -1):

Here is a recursive descent parser I ported to C:
http://www.gabotronics.com/resources/recursive-descent-parser.htm

Comment: Please consider adding an exerpt and some example code for future searchers who may stumble across this answer, in case the link doesn't always work.